# How do I sub in data in a variable name, Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

So I've got

```
LanRole.where("lan_id = ?", requestable.id).each do |lan_role| %>
    <% @lan_??? = Lan.find(lan_role.lan_id) %>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#lan_info_<%= lan.id %>"><%= lan.name %> INFO</a></li>
```

Where `???` should be lan_role.id so that i can put it in the tab later

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="lan_info_<%= lan.id %>" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h4><%= @lan_???.name %> INFO</h4>
    etc
  </div>
```

But I don't know how to make a variable variable name, sub it in there.

If it was a string, I could do

```
#{lan_role.id}
```

but it's not a string.

... I misread the error, it's on `<div id="lan_info_<%= lan.id %>" class="tab-pane fade">`

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `lan' for #<#<Class:0x007f7afb9e98a0>:0x007f7afb28aeb0>):
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here with a dynamic variable name? Why is that necessary? Why not just `@lan_id = ...`?

Comment: PSA: You can also do `where(lan_id: requestable.id)` if that's an ActiveRecord scope.

Comment: Is this Rails or something else?

Comment: It's not clear what "later" means. What value(s) from the LanRole record(s) are you looking to access? If you want free access to all of them, consider `x = LanRole.where(...).index_by(&:id)` which gives you a Hash look-up table to all records, so you can `x[n].name` where `n` is an ID.

Comment: yes rails, ty.  i misread the error actually, and updated the question

Comment: You have a `lan_role` variable, not `lan`. If this is a relation through LanRole, maybe you mean `lan_role.lan` as that should `belong_to`.

Comment: BTW, mixing HTML and Ruby inside an ERB template can become quite confusing. You should follow Rails' MVC pattern: make database queries in your controller and pass the relevant data to your view (see the example [Showing a List of Articles](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#showing-a-list-of-articles)). That way, you have pure Ruby code in your controller (easier to work with) and your view code becomes as simple as `<% @lan_roles.each do |lan_role| %>`.

Comment: _LanRole.where("lan_id = ?", requestable.id)_ and _Lan.find(lan_role.lan_id)_ — you should avoid such queries in the views. Especially second one because it can raise error

Answer (score 1):

For "variable" variables:

```rb
{one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}.each do |name, id|
  instance_variable_set("@lan_#{name}", [id, name])
  p @lan_one, @lan_two, @lan_three
end

[1, :one]
nil
nil
[1, :one]
[2, :two]
nil
[1, :one]
[2, :two]
[3, :three]
```

But since you're making tabs, just have two loops, one for links and one for bodies:

```rb
collection = LanRole.where("lan_id = ?", requestable.id)

# make tabs
collection.each do |role|
  role.name
end

# make tab contents
# collection is now loaded it won't hit the database again, at least it shouldn't
collection.each do |role|
  role.description
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it bu using **instance_variable_set** and **instance_variable_get** like this:

```
<% LanRole.where("lan_id = ?", requestable.id).each do |lan_role| %>
    <% instance_variable_set(:"@lan_#{lan_role.lan_id}", Lan.find(lan_role.lan_id)) %>
<% end %>
```

Then when you try to get it out use:

```
<h4><%= instance_variable_get(:"@lan_#{lan_role.lan_id}").name %> INFO</h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`instance_variable_set`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) and [`instance_variable_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) to set and get instance variables with dynamic names, but the is cumbersome. And unless you are doing meta-programming (and especially in your example) I would call using those methods a code-smell.

Instead, the go-to data structure to store data by a key is using a [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Hash.html). In your example, utilizing a Hash to store data by its `id` could look like this:

```
<% @lans_by_id = {} %>
<% LanRole.where("lan_id = ?", requestable.id).each do |lan_role| %>
  <% @lans_by_id[lan_role.lan_id] = Lan.find(lan_role.lan_id) %>
  # ...
```

And you can read the data similarly later in your code:

```
<h4><%= @lans_by_id[lan_role.lan_id].name %> INFO</h4>
```

**But:** You tagged your question with Ruby on Rails and instances of `LanRole` have a `lan_id` attribute already. Therefore, I suggest that you take advantage of Ruby on Rails and configure proper [`Active Record Associations`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) between your models.

When you configure the associations between `LanRole` and `Lan` like this:

```
# in app/models/lan_role.rb
class LanRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :lan
  # ... 

#in app/models/lan.rb
class LanRole < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lan_roles # or just `has_one :lan_role`?
```

When you have those associations set up in your models, then you can get the `lan` for a given `lan_role` by calling `lan_role.lan` instead of `Lan.find(lan_role.lan_id)`. And to avoid loading one `lan` in each block of the `each` iteration, I recommend eager loading all associated `lans`with [`includes`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#includes) at once.

Putting is all together: Loading and iterating

```
LanRole.where(lan_id: requestable.id).includes(:lan).each do |lan_role| %>
```

And then later using the associated `lan` like this:

```
<h4><%= lan_role.lan.name %> INFO</h4>
```